# Convert 12-hour time format to 24 hour integer?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, string, parsing

In my app I have a drop-down box of strings that shows possible hours in 12-hour time for the user to select.  The possible values are:

```
9am
10am
11am
12pm
1pm
2pm
3pm
4pm
5pm
```

What code will convert one of these strings to a 24 hour integer? For example, `10am` should be converted to `10` and `4pm` should be converted to `16`.

Answer (score 11):

You can use DateTime.Parse(...) to get a DateTime value, and then reference the `.Hour` property for a result;

```
int h = DateTime.Parse("10am").Hour;   // == 10
int h2 = DateTime.Parse("10pm").Hour;  // == 22
```

DateTime.Parse is pretty liberal in what it allows, but obviously makes some assumptions internally. For example, in the above code, `DateTime.Parse("10am")` returns 10am on the current date in the current timezone (I think...). So, be aware of the context in which you use the API.

Comment: That is awesome. It the `Parse` really that liberal? You don't even need to pass the format in which the time is given? Also, what if the `CurrentCulture` has some other defaults for `am`/`pm`? Could that happen? I would suggest passing the format after all. It is a simple one anyways.

Comment: Yep, why roll your own when someone else [will do/has done] it for you. :-)

Comment: Can `.TryParse` be used instead of `.Parse`?

Comment: @CJ7 Always, but unneeded if you trust the format of your items.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a dropdown, why not set the values to be the integer values you desire:

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="hours">
    <asp:ListItem Value="9">9am</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="10">10am</asp:ListItem>
    <!-- etc. -->
    <asp:ListItem Value="17">5pm</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering the times are continuous, you can simplify the logic:

```
var firstHourStr = box.Items[0].ToString();
var firstHour = int.Parse(firstHourStr.Replace("am", "").Replace("pm", ""));

if (firstHourStr.Contains("pm"))
{
    firstHour += 12;
}

var selectedHour = firstHour + box.SelectedIndex;
```

If the hours are static, and you know the first hour, you could have a const and simplify the process by much with `var selectedHour = FIRST_HOUR + box.SelectedIndex`.

Also, I assumed valid formats as shown in the question.

Final note: You'll need to handle the `12pm` case which causes problems, due to the nature of the hour 12 being a single second after "am".

Answer (score 1):

You could use `DateTime.Parse`, but that would not play nicely with internationalization.

```
int hour = DateTime.Parse(stringValue).Hour;
```

Instead, just use `DateTime` objects in the `ComboBox` and format them using FormatString:

```
// In Constructor:
cbHours.Items.Add(new DateTime(2000, 1, 1, 8, 0, 0));
cbHours.Items.Add(new DateTime(2000, 1, 1, 10, 0, 0));
cbHours.Items.Add(new DateTime(2000, 1, 1, 13, 0, 0));
cbHours.FormatString = "h tt";

// In event handler
if (cbHours.SelectedIndex >= 0)
{
    int hour = ((DateTime)cbHours.SelectedItem).Hour
    // do things with the hour
}
```